# Видимость только для определенной группы пользователей.

Tags: php

Второй вопрос за сегодня. Допустим, у меня есть ссылка.

`<a href='../acm/bla-bla.php'>ололо</a>`

Так же, при входе в сессии сохраняется некое число. Это тип пользователя. 1 - обычный, 2 - админ. Допустим, что он будет храниться в переменной **$category**. Как примерно набросить, чтобы ссылку могли видеть только пользователи, имеющие в сессии эту самую 2?

Comment: если админ, то рисуем ссылку...

if ($category==2) print 'ваша ссылка'?

Answer (score 1):

Вместо этого текста пишешь:

```
<?php
if ($category == 2) 
    echo "<a href='../acm/bla-bla.php'>ололо</a>";
?>
```

Comment: @IVsevolod - а в чем собственно проблема ? сессии хранятся на сервере, и вроде как это обычный способ хранить данные по юзеру, скажем бывает что `$_SESSION['user']=new User($login,$password);` (в обработчике авторизации)  и там  хранится объект класса User у которого, в том числе, есть метод is_admin(); в kayako так сделано например, да и вообще почти везде.

Comment: Присоеденяюсь к вопросу. Может я чего не знаю :)

Comment: @eicto извиняюсь, немного заработался.., В общем с тем предложением я был не прав :)